# How can I show a new file/webpage using ActiveJob in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable, wicked-pdf, rails-activejob

I used to generate PDFs for my users by using the `wicked_pdf` gem and writing 
something like the example code below:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "file_name"   # Excluding ".pdf" extension.
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I would then have a link on a page like `<%= link_to report_pdf_path(@report), "Download PDF", target: "_blank" %>` that would cause the PDF to show up in the user's browser as a new tab. This is the preferred behavior I would like, but it halts all requests until the PDF is completed for the user and some of these take quite some time to generate.

So I've since offloaded the generating of the PDF to ActiveJob which works nice, but I can't figure out how to have ActiveJob open the file in a new window yet.  Currently, I have it writing to the server and then updating a partial that shows the files the user has requested.  Below is an example of it.

```
class GeneratePdfJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    params = args.first
    generate_pdf_document(params)
  end

  def generate_pdf_document(params)
    html = ApplicationController.new.render_to_string(
      template: 'players/board_labels.pdf.erb',
       locals: { player_ids: params[:player_ids] }
      )
    save_to_pdf(html, params[:pdf_title], params[:user_code])
  end

  def save_to_pdf(html, pdf_title, user_code)
    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
           html,
            pdf: "#{pdf_title}",
         layout: 'print',
       encoding: 'utf-8'
      )
    pdf_name = "#{pdf_title}.pdf"
    pdf_dir = Rails.root.join('public','uploads','reports',"#{user_code}")
    pdf_path = Rails.root.join(pdf_dir,pdf_name)
    # create the folder if it doesn't exist
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(pdf_dir) unless File.directory?(pdf_dir)
    # create a new file
    File.open(pdf_path,'wb') do |file|
      file.binmode
      file << pdf.force_encoding("UTF-8")
    end
  end

end
```

So how can I make a method that would replace the `save_to_pdf` method and instead open the file in a new tab for the user?  If this isn't possible could I open a tab when I initiate the ActiveJob that is a placeholder tab and then incorporate ActionCable to display the file some how after it's been generated for the user?

Comment: If the user has to wait for Activejob to be processed, is it much better than waiting for the web server to process it ? What would be best is to anticipate on the user action and preprocess it. Though if this isn't possible, you can open a new tab with an Ajax script that pings the server every 3 seconds to check if file is present. I have something similar and can show you my code if you go this way.

Comment: @Maxence, by allowing Active Job to do the work and then display when ready I get the same functionality where it pops up in a new tab - but it doesn't keep them from navigating the site if the report is taking upwards of 4/5 mins to generate.

Comment: This is high level ideas for you to consider. 

[1] When user request for PDF file, you send the request to ActiveJob. At the same time, starts a polling service in client (user's broweser) to check if the job is finished or still in the queue. If it's done, show the download link. 

[2] Use Rails ActionCable WebSocket. In your ActiveJob function, add method to broadcast to the channel that the user is subscribed to. So, when client (browser) get the data from the server (via ActionCable), it can shows the download link. 

Good luck!